# codeigniter carabiner not compressing or combining css

Tags: php, codeigniter, carabiner

I am trying this for last two days without any luck. I have used carabiner to handle the assets on my site amitavroy.com

When I put that configuration of carabiner to production my js files are getting combined and compressed
But for some reason the css files don't even get combined forget about compression.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old topic but, maybe, this will help others newbies.

```
 $this->load->library('carabiner');
    $carabiner_config = array(
        'script_dir' => 'js/',
        'style_dir' => 'css/',
        'cache_dir' => 'cache/',
        'base_uri' => base_url(),
        'combine' => TRUE,
        'dev' => FALSE,
        'minify_js' => TRUE,
        'minify_css' => TRUE     // <- this should do the trick
    );
    $this->carabiner->config($carabiner_config);
```